# Django list of choices in MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to display in a form every existing graph_id that exists in the GraphData model. like so:

```py
GRAPHS_CHOICES = (GraphData.objects.all().values_list("graph_id", flat=True).distinct())

class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    graphs = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=GRAPHS_CHOICES)
```

```py
class GraphData(models.Model):
    graph_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=128)
```

The problem is that choices expects a tuple, and not a list of id's. How can I supply it with a list anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you can change a QuerySet to tuple with this

```
query_tuple = [(q['id'], q['name']) for q in queryset]
```